# Model index.html page displaying duplicated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting some strange behavior on my model index page. When I create one model object, it displays correctly on the index page. When I create a second model object, it shows duplicates of both objects on the index page, like so

```
OBJECT A
OBJECT B
OBJECT A
OBJECT B
```

I've confirmed that duplicate objects are not being created in my database. Also, when I destroy OBJECT B, it displays OBJECT A correctly only once.

index.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>URL</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <%= render @companies %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

_company.html.erb

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image_tag company.image(:medium) %></td>
    <td><%= company.name %></td>
    <td><%= company.description %></td>
    <td><%= company.url %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', company %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_company_path(company) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', company, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

companies_controller.rb

```
def index
    @companies = Company.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @companies }
    end
  end
```

Comment: What's the name of the partial that you linked here?

Comment: Please post your controller code for the `index` action.  Maybe trim down the HTML in your example, too; the `<th>` lines aren't important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your partial to,

```
<tr>
  <td><%= image_tag company.image(:medium) %></td>
  <td><%= company.name %></td>
  <td><%= company.description %></td>
  <td><%= company.url %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', company %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_company_path(company) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', company, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

You need to drop the each loop in your partial.

The `<%= render @companies %>` renders the partial for each company but you're also looping through the companies again in each partial.

See **3.4.5 Rendering Collections** at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections for more info

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<%= render @companies %>` to `<%= render "company" %>`; your partial is being rendered multiple times, one for each company, and your partial is rendering all the companies. This will only render the partial, which will render all the companies, which is what you want.